# Rails split form field into two, i.e metres and milimetres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a number_field in rails, is there an easy way to split the input box into two parts, i.e have an input for metres and another for millimetres?

Comment: What type is your attribute - string or a float?

Comment: the attribute is decimal

Comment: So you're saving the value in millimetres, but want it to be editable in metres and millimetres?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two virtual attributes on your model. I assume your model is called `Model` and the existing attribute is called `unit`.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :unit_metres, :unit_millimetres

  def unit_metres=(value)
    @unit_metres = value
    self.unit = @unit_metres * 1000 + unit_millimetres
  end

  def unit_millimetres=(value)
    @unit_millimetres = value
    self.unit = unit_metres + @unit_millimetres
  end
end
```

Now, instead of using `<%= number_field :unit %>` in your form, use `<%= number_field :unit_metres %>` and `<%= number_field :unit_millimetres %>`.

Comment: I decided against doing this so I haven't tested your code but won't you just have an endless loop here with each method calling each other?

Comment: No, the setters are calling the opposite getters, not each other.